# To suddenly log-out after upgrade Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, lts

When I Upgraded my system from 15.10 to 16.04, one my drive was mounted and after restart gave a message like :

`/dev/sda3: clean, 236680/38944768 files, 12412333/155760896 blocks`

and now **after and before each log-in / log-off** see this message and also suddenly **the system become log-off !!!**

Also the first time my partition from`NTFS` became to `RAW` that solved this problem by `ntfsfix` but now see that message `clean /dev/sda3/ ...` too.

thanks so much if you have an idea to solve it :)

Comment: Have you checked this https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminal/+question/292147

Comment: @bhordupur __ Yes I saw it before. my problem is log-out suddenly

Answer (score 0):

I saw my graphic drive was `Xorg S Server` and I change it to `Nvidia` (my graphic drive gf-210 ) and now is okay.

no `/dev/sda3: clean, 236680/38944768 files, 12412333/155760896 blocks`
and no `log-out`

Someone offer me to edit `fstab` but after edition it, I had the problem.

and I also saw the cause of the **lout-out** was form `gnome-session`